# Spring cloud stream / Kafka exceptions

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I have problems with a service which uses spring cloud stream and kafka.  The service had been working ok, but yesterday started reporting a series of exceptions on startup:

```
Checking for rethrow: count=2
2018-09-11 10:43:34.904 DEBUG [payment-gateway,,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=2
2018-09-11 10:43:34.904 DEBUG [payment-gateway,,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'payment-reply', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[1478], headers={errorChannel=e61450f9-fa47-446f-95ae-5021868cadfa:602, deliveryAttempt=3, X-B3-ParentSpanId=a9fe9b1c87b14698, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedTopic=paymentResponse, spanTraceId=966a10371583367f, spanId=7aa71302bc18bb4c, spanParentSpanId=a9fe9b1c87b14698, replyChannel=e61450f9-fa47-446f-95ae-5021868cadfa:601, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[966a10371583367f], spanId=[7aa71302bc18bb4c], spanParentSpanId=[a9fe9b1c87b14698], spanSampled=[0]}, kafka_offset=2299, X-B3-SpanId=7aa71302bc18bb4c, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@2fb81502, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=966a10371583367f, spanSampled=0, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1536592853999}]
2018-09-11 10:43:34.904 DEBUG [payment-gateway,966a10371583367f,c94b21ccaaed668b,false] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.i.m.TracingChannelInterceptor    : Created a new span in pre sendNoopSpan{context=966a10371583367f/c94b21ccaaed668b}
2018-09-11 10:43:34.905 DEBUG [payment-gateway,966a10371583367f,4476713d70434d52,false] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.i.m.TracingChannelInterceptor    : Created a new span in before handleNoopSpan{context=966a10371583367f/e1d1a2a6b9ad093e}
2018-09-11 10:43:34.905 DEBUG [payment-gateway,966a10371583367f,4476713d70434d52,false] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.i.m.TracingChannelInterceptor    : Will finish the current span after message handled NoopSpan{context=966a10371583367f/4476713d70434d52}
2018-09-11 10:43:34.905 DEBUG [payment-gateway,966a10371583367f,c94b21ccaaed668b,false] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.i.m.TracingChannelInterceptor    : Will finish the current span after completion NoopSpan{context=966a10371583367f/c94b21ccaaed668b}
2018-09-11 10:43:34.905 DEBUG [payment-gateway,,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Received: 0 records
2018-09-11 10:43:35.001 DEBUG [payment-gateway,,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Commit list: {}
2018-09-11 10:43:35.002 DEBUG [payment-gateway,,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-gateway] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 0 for partition refundResponse-0 returned fetch data (error=NONE, highWaterMark=0, lastStableOffset = -1, logStartOffset = 0, abortedTransactions = null, recordsSizeInBytes=0)
2018-09-11 10:43:35.002 DEBUG [payment-gateway,,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-gateway] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition refundResponse-0 at offset 0 to node 10.244.0.194:9092 (id: 2 rack: null)
2018-09-11 10:43:35.002 DEBUG [payment-gateway,,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-gateway] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch for partitions [refundResponse-0] to broker 10.244.0.194:9092 (id: 2 rack: null)
2018-09-11 10:43:35.003 DEBUG [payment-gateway,,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=3
2018-09-11 10:43:35.003 DEBUG [payment-gateway,,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry failed last attempt: count=3
2018-09-11 10:43:35.004 DEBUG [payment-gateway,,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.i.h.a.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer   : Sending ErrorMessage: failedMessage: GenericMessage [payload=byte[1478], headers={errorChannel=e61450f9-fa47-446f-95ae-5021868cadfa:602, deliveryAttempt=3, X-B3-ParentSpanId=7aa71302bc18bb4c, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedTopic=paymentResponse, spanTraceId=966a10371583367f, spanId=c94b21ccaaed668b, spanParentSpanId=7aa71302bc18bb4c, replyChannel=e61450f9-fa47-446f-95ae-5021868cadfa:601, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[966a10371583367f], spanId=[c94b21ccaaed668b], spanParentSpanId=[7aa71302bc18bb4c], spanSampled=[0]}, kafka_offset=2299, X-B3-SpanId=c94b21ccaaed668b, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@2fb81502, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=966a10371583367f, id=83994228-ba45-2303-1f7e-2eaf8f49c400, spanSampled=0, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1536592853999, timestamp=1536662614904}]
2018-09-11 08:44:19.837 ERROR [payment-gateway,bd9888a7d590ebf7,535db983ae0aedab,false] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : 
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: 
Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application-1.payment-reply'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: 
Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[1197], headers={errorChannel=e61450f9-fa47-446f-95ae-5021868cadfa:426, deliveryAttempt=3, X-B3-ParentSpanId=760139e0bc5d9ac0, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedTopic=paymentResponse, spanTraceId=bd9888a7d590ebf7, spanId=5c6ac2c521faf6e7, spanParentSpanId=760139e0bc5d9ac0, replyChannel=e61450f9-fa47-446f-95ae-5021868cadfa:425, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[bd9888a7d590ebf7], spanId=[535db983ae0aedab], spanParentSpanId=[5c6ac2c521faf6e7], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[bd9888a7d590ebf7], X-B3-SpanId=[535db983ae0aedab], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[5c6ac2c521faf6e7], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, kafka_offset=2258, X-B3-SpanId=5c6ac2c521faf6e7, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@59715a4a, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=bd9888a7d590ebf7, id=88531659-3fb0-a59f-bb69-54c9ba82d608, spanSampled=0, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1536592840192, timestamp=1536655459828}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[1197], headers={errorChannel=e61450f9-fa47-446f-95ae-5021868cadfa:426, deliveryAttempt=3, X-B3-ParentSpanId=760139e0bc5d9ac0, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedTopic=paymentResponse, spanTraceId=bd9888a7d590ebf7, spanId=5c6ac2c521faf6e7, spanParentSpanId=760139e0bc5d9ac0, replyChannel=e61450f9-fa47-446f-95ae-5021868cadfa:425, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[bd9888a7d590ebf7], spanId=[535db983ae0aedab], spanParentSpanId=[5c6ac2c521faf6e7], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[bd9888a7d590ebf7], X-B3-SpanId=[535db983ae0aedab], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[5c6ac2c521faf6e7], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, kafka_offset=2258, X-B3-SpanId=5c6ac2c521faf6e7, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@59715a4a, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=bd9888a7d590ebf7, id=88531659-3fb0-a59f-bb69-54c9ba82d608, spanSampled=0, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1536592840192, timestamp=1536655459828}]
            at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
```

after some time we then see exceptions like this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name '946859a6-bc27-466d-91ba-3da93af50ac9:1' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '946859a6-bc27-466d-91ba-3da93af50ac9:1' available
```

the connection to kafka is configured with a property: `spring.kafka.bootstrap-server = kafka.kafka:9092`

and the topics are configured with spring cloud stream properties: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.[topic-name].destination = blah`

The interaction with kafka goes via spring integration with code like this:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface StreamGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = KafkaConfig.ENRICH_PAYMENT, replyChannel = ChannelNames.PAYMENT_REPLY, replyTimeout = 10000)
    String processPayment(String payload);

}
```

//Different class:

```
private final StreamGateway gateway;
...
gateway.processPayment(message)
```

This is running on an azure kubernetes deployment, and kafka is in a separate pod from the spring boot service.

thanks in advance.

**Update:**
The problem reoccured and some further investigation has highlighted a couple of things

- Because we're using spring integration `@MessagingGateway` and `@Gateway` to create a synchronous interaction with Kafka, there is no normal topic `StreamListener` or subscriber
- The problem is occurring when there is a **lag** on the topic, i.e. there are messages in the topic beyond the topic offset.
- The lack of a normal `StreamListener` means the lag messages have no means of being processed.  Only when a connection is made by the MessageGateway, is it possible for messages to be read from the topic.
- One means of getting rid of the problem is to read all 'lag' messages, so that the lag is 0.  The service will then start normally, however if I manually post messages to the topic (out-with the MessageGateway interaction), then the error reoccurs.
- A second partial solution (which I dont fully understand yet) is to add a `@DependsOn` annotation to the MessageGateway, indicating that it requires a bean separately created with a `@Input` SubscribableChannel object.  This means the SubscribableChannel must be created before the MessageGateway, therefore creating a Subscriber, however there is still no StreamListener, so exceptions are still thrown as lag messages are pulled from the topic, with no-where to go

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure about the details of your application, what is clear is that a Message gets delivered to an `application-1.payment-reply` channel which, as the error states, *has no subscriber*. Basically it means there is no listener on that channel (such as `@StreamListener` or `@ServiceActivator` etc).

It is a very common Spring Integration miss-configuration, but without looking at your app it is hard to say where it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it is this application (the one failing to start) which should be listening to the payment-reply topic.  There is a separate service the posts to that topic

Comment: I've added an example of how we're calling the channels.

Comment: I don't think there is enough details here. Let's try the other way. The exception you see is pure Spring Integration and has nothing to do with Kafka, Azur or anything else, so it should be easily reproducible in a slim down version of the app.
Another possibility (given that you mention startup) is that something is not starting up due to some failure and due to such failure the listener is not registered. So may be a more comprehensive stack trace?

Comment: added more stack trace to question

Answer (score 0):

On looking at the debug log I noticed that the service was connecting to other topics correctly, but having problems with the payment-reply topic.  I tried deleting this topic and restarting the service.  This fixed the problem.